# Prevent webpage from scrolling to top when clicked on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have links attached to jquery and when i click on the links the page scrolls back to the top.

How can i prevent this from happening. In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dF28/) you can see, if you scroll down to check 7, and click, it the page scrolls back to the top.

Please help.

HTML:

```
<ul class="leftlist">
                    <li itemage="" id="1013" class="todo"><a href="#" class="strike">           
                    <span class="cb check_box"></span>

        <p>Check One</p></a>           
                    </li><li itemage="" id="1014" class="todo"><a href="#" class="strike">           
                    <span class="cb check_box"></span>

        <p>Check two</p></a>           
                    </li><li itemage="" id="1018" class="todo"><a href="#">           
                    <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

        <p>Check 3</p></a>           
                    </li><li itemage="" id="1019" class="todo"><a href="#">           
                    <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

        <p>Check 4</p></a>           
                    </li><li itemage="" id="1024" class="todo"><a href="#">           
                    <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

        <p>Check 5</p></a>           
                    </li><li itemage="1" id="1021" class="todo"><a href="#">           
                    <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

        <p>Check 6</p></a>           
                    </li><li itemage="3" id="1025" class="todo"><a href="#">           
                    <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

        <p>Check 7</p></a>           

        </li></ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
(function($){
        $('li.todo').click(function(){
            if($(this).find('.uncheck_box').length >0){
                var _t=$(this).find('.uncheck_box');
                _t.removeClass('uncheck_box');
                _t.addClass('check_box');
                m_val='1';
                $(this).find('a').addClass('strike');
            }else{
                m_val='0';
                var _t=$(this).find('.check_box');
                _t.removeClass('check_box');
                _t.addClass('uncheck_box');
                $(this).find('a').removeClass('strike');
            }
        var m_key=jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax_get.php",
              data: { meta_key: m_key, meta_value: m_val},
               beforeSend: function(   ) {
                 //jQuery(this).attr("disabled", true);       
              },
              success:function(){}
            })
        });



    $('.sort').click(function(){
        var _t=$(this);
        $('.sort').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        if(_t.hasClass('showall')){
            $('li.todo').show();
        }else if(_t.hasClass('complete')){
            $('li.todo').show();
            $('li.todo').filter(function(){
                return !!$(this).find('span.uncheck_box').length;
            }).hide();
        }else if(_t.hasClass('incomplete')){
            $('li.todo').show();
            $('li.todo').filter(function(){
                return !!$(this).find('span.check_box').length;
            }).hide();
        }

    });


    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
        jQuery('.chkbx').click(function(){

        var cuser_id='<?php echo $current_user->ID;?>';
        var m_val='0';
        if(jQuery(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            m_val='1';
            jQuery(this).parent().next("dd").addClass('strike');
        }else
        {
            m_val='0';
            jQuery(this).parent().next("dd").removeClass('strike');
        }
        var m_key=jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax_get/",
              data: { meta_key: m_key, meta_value: m_val},
               beforeSend: function(   ) {
                 jQuery(this).attr("disabled", true);         }
            })
              .done(function( msg ) {
              jQuery(this).attr("disabled", false);     
              });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
<a href="javascript:;">Your content</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the `#` in `<a href="#">` replace this with `<a href="javascript:void(0);">`

http://jsfiddle.net/8dF28/2/

Comment: this doesnt work as then it leads to another page "not found"

Comment: The scroll is caused by the `#` because it links to the top. By using the `void(0);` it does nothing. The navigation should then be caused by the Javascript. As you can see in the Fiddle it does not scroll with `void(0);`

Comment: make sure you added `javascript:` in front of `void(0);`